# How to fill in an executable's details with MS Visual C++?

Tags: c++, exe

I want to deploy my program that I created with MS Visual C++ 2010 and I would like to fill in the description strings such as product name, product version, copyright (right-click on exe -> "details" tab).

I have tried using ResHack but nothing editable shows up there, so I'm asking how to fill that stuff in with MS Visual C++

Any ideas? Thanks =)

.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to fill the VS_VERSION_INFO in resource editor (VS2010)?

Comment: Nothing happens when I press Ctrl+Shift+E edit: seems the editor is not included in the express version... hm

Comment: It seems that Express version doesn't have the resource editor. Perhaps this should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I will just not do it then, it's too complicated but thanks =)

Comment: @JoelleDenby Resource files in Windows are just XML-files that you can edit with any text editor, so even though the Visual Studio 2010 Express IDE is missing the resource editor does not mean you can't use resources. See [Resource Files(Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zxb70x7(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Okay =) But I don't need to plough through that anymore since I just got the Professional version from a friend of mine and now I can use its resource editor. Suddenly everything is so simple!!